# After copying my itunes library to my Ubuntu partition, how can I rename mp3s to their correct name?

Tags: music, files, mp3, mp3-tag

Because of how itunes organizes files, I have a bunch of mp3s that are organized in folders named `F00` through `F49`. The files themselves have names like `AVCH.mp3`. How can I rename these to their proper name?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using [tagtool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tagtool) [image: Install tagtool] to rename the files based on their tags.

[image]

Useful link:

- [Tagtool - Tool to tag and rename MP3 and Ogg Vorbis files](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tagtool-tool-to-tag-and-rename-mp3-and-ogg-vorbis-files.html)